# Regarding this linear algebra problem (matrix violation), I would like to ask which answer step I wrote wrong?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, block-matrices

I would list the stem first and then give my two solutions, but the answers are not the same,
something must be wrong here.

**question：**

matrix ***A*** is
$
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 &  0& 0 &1 \\
  0& 1 & 1 & 0\\
  0&  1& -1 &0 \\
  1&  0&  0&-1
\end{pmatrix}
$
and matrix ***B*** is
$
\begin{pmatrix}
 0&  0& 0 &1 \\
  0& 0 & 1 & 0\\
  0&  1& 0 &0 \\
  1&  0&  0&0
\end{pmatrix}
$

Then,what is the value of matrix ***ABA***?

**1. My method one:**

> Use block matrix:

matrix ***A*** =
$
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 &  0& 0 &1 \\
  0& 1 & 1 & 0\\
  0&  1& -1 &0 \\
  1&  0&  0&-1
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
 E & C\\
  C&-E
\end{pmatrix}
$
and
matrix ***B*** =
$
\begin{pmatrix}
 0&  0& 0 &1 \\
  0& 0 & 1 & 0\\
  0&  1& 0 &0 \\
  1&  0&  0&0
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & C\\
  C&0
\end{pmatrix}$

so matric ***ABA*** =
$\begin{pmatrix}
 E & C\\
  C&-E
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & C\\
  C&0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
 E & C\\
  C&-E
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 2E&0 \\
  0&-2E
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
 2&  0& 0 &0 \\
  0& 2 & 0 & 0\\
  0&  0& -2 &0 \\
  0&  0&  0&-2
\end{pmatrix}$

**2. My method two:**

> There should be something wrong with this method, but I can't find it.

matrix ***A*** =
$
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 &  0& 0 &1 \\
  0& 1 & 1 & 0\\
  0&  1& -1 &0 \\
  1&  0&  0&-1
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
 1 &  1& 0 &0 \\
  1& -1 & 0 & 0\\
  0&  0& 1 &1 \\
  0&  0&  1&-1
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
 D & 0\\
  0& D
\end{pmatrix} 
$

and
matrix ***B*** =
$
\begin{pmatrix}
 0&  0& 0 &1 \\
  0& 0 & 1 & 0\\
  0&  1& 0 &0 \\
  1&  0&  0&0
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
 1&  0& 0 &0 \\
  0& 1 & 0 & 0\\
  0&  0& 1 &0 \\
  0&  0&  0&1
\end{pmatrix}=E
$

so matric ***ABA*** =***AEA***= $A^2=
\begin{pmatrix}
 D^2 & 0\\
  0& D^2
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
 2&  0& 0 &0 \\
  0& 2 & 0 & 0\\
  0&  0& 2 &0 \\
  0&  0&  0&2
\end{pmatrix}$

You can notice that the two methods get different answers, the problem should be with method 2, but I can't find it.

**thanks for your help!**

Comment: Can you explain this step ? $$\begin{pmatrix}
 1 &  0& 0 &1 \\
  0& 1 & 1 & 0\\
  0&  1& -1 &0 \\
  1&  0&  0&-1
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
 1 &  1& 0 &0 \\
  1& -1 & 0 & 0\\
  0&  0& 1 &1 \\
  0&  0&  1&-1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Looks like you did some elementary transformations on your matrices. The resulting matrices are not equal to the starting ones, and you can't expect when you multiply different matrices that you'll get the same result. Let me show you why that can't work using $1\times 1$ matrices, aka numbers. Let $A = 1$ and $B = 2$. Then $ABA = 2$. Let me now do elementary transformations on $A$ and $B$, let's say multiply it's rows by $3$, to get $A' = 3$, $B' = 6$.  Note that $A'B'A' = 54 \neq 2$.

Comment: My idea is that the elementary transformations of matrices are equivalent to each other. Here, the rows and columns are moved so that they can become block matrices.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just realized my mistake!

Comment: Therefore, the eigenvalues ​​and the corresponding equation solutions are not changed by the elementary transformation of the matrix, but as a calculation item, does the transformation change its value?

Comment: @BarryAlen you need to write down exactly what you did if you want precise answer. Note that in my previous example performing elementary transformations on matrices in fact changed eigenvalues.  To preserve eigenvalues you need to do something like $A' =S^{-1}AS$, since $\det(A-tI) = \det (S^{-1}(A-tI)S) = \det(A'-tI)$.

Comment: It seems like you'd like to do something like this: $A' = S^{-1}AS$, $B' = S^{-1}BS$. Then $A'B'A' = (S^{-1}AS)(S^{-1}BS)(S^{-1}AS) = S^{-1}(ABA)S$, so $ABA = S(A'B'A')S^{-1}$. Note that result is still not necessarily equal, but by writing transformations explicitly, you can extract the product you want.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply!@Ennar 
For matric ***A***  I do swap the 2nd and 4th row and then swap the 2nd and 4th column.Sorry, I'm not very good at describing in mathematical language，maybe it 
can be described as "$E(2,4)AE(3,4)$"

Answer (score 1):

I will compile my comments into an answer.

If you do elementary transformations on your matrices, the resulting matrices are not equal to the starting ones, and you can't expect when you multiply different matrices that you'll get the same result. Let me show you why that can't work using $1×1$ matrices, aka numbers.

Let $A=1$ and $B=2$. Then, $ABA=2$. Let me now do elementary transformations on $A$ and $B$, let's say multiply its rows by $3$ to get $A′=3$, $B′=6$. Note that $A′B′A′=54≠2$.

It seems like you'd like to do something like this: $A′=S^{−1}AS$, $B′=S^{−1}BS$. Then, $$A′B′A′=(S^{−1}AS)(S^{−1}BS)(S^{−1}AS)=S^{−1}(ABA)S,$$ so $ABA=S(A′B′A′)S^{−1}.$ Note that result is still not necessarily equal, but by writing transformations explicitly, you can extract the product you want.

Also note that I do same transformations **both** to $A$ and $B$, so that $S^{−1}$ and $S$ cancel when we expand the product $A'B'A'$.

Let's say that $S$ is matrix corresponding to switching 2nd and 4th row/column (depending on which side we multiply). It's clear that $S^{−1} = S$, since if we do the switch twice, we get back to the same matrix.

Now,

$$A'\! =\! S^{-1}AS\! =\!\! \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right)\!\! \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\!\!  \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)\!\! =\!\! \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
*(notice that you have a mistake in your calculation).*

Let's do the same for $B$:

$$
B' = S^{-1}BS = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right) \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)  \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

You can verify that

$$A'B'A' = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ and that $$ABA = S(A'B'A')S^{-1} = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -2 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$